# How to find Chrome's installed plugins (*not* extensions)

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, plugins

Google Chrome is slowly trying to block out people using plug ins so they'll instead use their extensions. They're even semi obfuscating these plugins, and I can't find a couple I have installed.

One I'm trying to remove because it's no longer supported and there's a replacement, but I don't want the old one sitting around. But I don't know how to find it, it's neither on the Extensions page (of course) but it's also not on `chrome://plugins/`. There are *some* plug ins there that can't be found in the extension page, but not all of them.

I know it's not just this specific plugin being funny, because I similarly can't see where the Java plugin is but it's definitely installed in Chrome (both notify me that they will soon lose support and can be enabled on sites).

So where else can I look for plugins that Chrome is using so that I can remove/uninstall/delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found that the reason for my confusion was that I considered this to be a Chrome plugin, but actually it's a browser agnostic installation. It's not tied to Chrome apart from being able to run in Chrome.

I was able to find the plugin by going to the AppData folder. To go there, open windows explorer, type in `%appdata%` and it will open the folder. There's a few different folders like local, roaming etc. The plugin I needed happened to be in Roaming. It was inside another folder that was relevantly named (ie. the plugin was Shotgun Integration and the folder was named Shotgun Software). So you'll need to search around to find your particular plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Google Chrome Version 44.0.2403.157 (64-bit) on Lubuntu 14.04. In my default profile I have this "text" file: `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences`.

Here's what I see in part and after a bit of reformatting:

```
"plugins":{"last_internal_directory":"/opt/google/chrome",  
"plugins_list":  
[{"enabled":true,"name":"Chrome PDF Viewer","path":"chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/","version":""},  
 {"enabled":true,"name":"Shockwave Flash","path":"/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so","version":"18.0.0.209"},  
 {"enabled":true,"name":"Chrome Remote Desktop Viewer","path":"internal-remoting-viewer","version":""},  
 {"enabled":true,"name":"Widevine Content Decryption Module","path":"/opt/google/chrome/libwidevinecdmadapter.so","version":"1.4.8.823"},  
 {"enabled":true,"name":"Native Client","path":"/opt/google/chrome/internal-nacl-plugin","version":""},  
 {"enabled":true,"name":"Chrome PDF Viewer","path":"internal-pdf-viewer","version":""},  
 {"enabled":true,"name":"Adobe Flash Player"},  
 {"enabled":true,"name":"Chrome PDF Viewer"},  
 {"enabled":true,"name":"Chrome Remote Desktop Viewer"},  
 {"enabled":true,"name":"Native Client"},  
 {"enabled":true,"name":"Widevine Content Decryption Module"}],  
 ...
```

The same plugins are visible in `chrome://plugins/`. I set `details` at the top-right of the page to *expanded* view.